# Re-entrant subprocesses in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a Python module that offloads some processing with the `subprocess` module. The module reads and writes data via the `subprocess.communicate` method using pipes over `stdin` and `stdout`. One of the subprocesses re-enters the Python module and spawns yet another subprocess. This deadlocks the application because the `stdin` and `stdout` file descriptors are in use by the parent subprocess.

Is there a way to avoid this deadlock without having to create and clean up temporary files everywhere?

Here is my scenario in more detail: it's a web app running inside a FastCGI server. When a request for a PDF file is made, a subprocess is spawned to launch a third-party application (wkhtmltopdf) to create the PDF. This application then begins to download images via my FastCGI module--in the *same process* as the parent process of the PDF creator. Retrieving the image invokes another third party application via `subprocess`, which deadlocks because `stdin` and `stdout` are already in use by the PDF creator subprocess.

This problem is alluded to in [this blog post](http://dcreager.net/2009/08/06/subprocess-communicate-drawbacks/) (at the end), but no follow-up solutions have been provided. I may have to resort to temporary files, but I prefer pipes. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: it sounds like you might want to look into a better IPC mechanism. You may want to look at zeromq, it makes these kind of things a lot easier to do without resorting to a big clunky messaging server like rabbitmq. http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all

Comment: Thanks @tom, unfortunately the FastCGI server is run on a shared hosting service. I managed to get around the issue by ironing out the re-entrant parts of the subprocess, but I'd still like to know if the general scenario is solvable.

Comment: hmmm well I don't know what restrictions the host might have but celery http://celeryproject.org/ can use processes so maybe that might be useful. if anything just looking at the code to see how they do it.

Comment: If available in your hosting service, [gearman](http://gearman.org/) might be another alternative to dispatch tasks to worker processes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your analysis is correct.

You say that the process deadlocks because stdin and stdout are in use by the PDF-creator process. However, since this was started using the subprocess module, the fds that are stdin and stdout for the PDF-creator-process, are just regular pipe fds for the FastCGI-process. There is no reason why you couldn't have multiple ongoing subprocess "communicate" calls ongoing at the same time.

However, note that "communicate" is a blocking call. While one thread in your process is running comnunicate, that thread will not be able to do anything else, like serving HTTP requests for images.

In this case, one solution is to make your server multi-threaded. I'm a bid surprised that it isn't already, since most web-servers can serve multiple requests simultaneously (in different threads), so this should "just work".

But maybe you're doing something wrong in how you use "communicate". I've written a small example of how to use multiple ongoing "communicate" invocations simultaneously in the same process, maybe you can use it as a base for a solution. Without knowing more about your problem it is hard to be of better service.

```
import subprocess
from threading import Thread


sp1 = subprocess.Popen(["bash","-c","sleep 2;echo output1"],
                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False,close_fds=True)

sp2 = subprocess.Popen(["bash","-c","sleep 1;echo output2"],
                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False,close_fds=True)

def readfrom(which,sp):
    print "Thread #%d starting."%(which,)
    (stdout, stderr) = sp.communicate()
    print "Thread #%d finished, output: %s"%(which,stdout)

t1=Thread(target=readfrom,args=(1,sp1))
t2=Thread(target=readfrom,args=(2,sp2))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Your solution doesn't seem to address the re-entrant part of the problem. What would happen if sp1 and sp2 re-entered the same process which then started a new sp1 and sp2? I believe the parent process deadlocks.

Comment: How do you mean re-enter the same process? There is no way for the subprocesses spawned by subprocess.Popen to somehow call the parent process directly. All they can do is communicate with the server process through pipes, sockets or something similar. Of course, if your server is busy waiting for the subprocesses to complete, you will have a dead lock, but this has nothing to do with any limitation in the python subprocess module. And the work-around is easy - run the subprocess.Popen calls in their own threads (like in my example above).

Comment: Consider a parent process that reads input from a pipe, calls a subprocess,  and writes the output of the subprocess back to the same pipe. Now what if this subprocess writes to the parent's input pipe and waits to read from the pipe? I believe the result is deadlock, and this kind of simulates the issue I was having. Sorry for my confusing terminology (this is what I meant be 're-entering the same process', I should have been more clear). In any case, the point is moot as I have redesigned the subprocess to simply avoid this possibility. Thanks for your replies.